# Azure: Cannot connect to remote debugger

Tags: debugging, azure, visual-studio-2015

I want to use Remote Debugger in Visual Studio 2015 to attach to my site. When I try "Attach Debugger" the azure return:
*The following error occurred while launching remote debugging: Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugger name 'XXXX'. Windows authentication was unable to establish a secure connection to the remote computer.*

In azure portal I set remote debugging and select VS 2015.

Answer (score 11):

These errors might be related to Local Policies > Security Options > Network Security: LAN manager authentication level. It needs to be set to “Send NTLMV2 response only”. Once this is set then the PC  was able to open RemoteApp applications without problems.

To set local policies go to command prompt and  type secpol.msc or  Administrative Tools > Local Security Policy

Comment: Thanx! Your suggestion solved my problem, and allowed me to connect to Azure for remote debugging.

Comment: I have this exact problem but with VS2017, and setting this option makes no difference.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me (also Visual Studio 2015).

Comment: brilliant! worked for the "authentication failed" issue also on VS2019

Comment: VS 2019: I still have this issue... `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x89710023): Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugger named 'myapidev.azurewebsites.net'. The input was in an unexpected format or value.`

Answer (score 4):

Maybe your application is not enabled to use remote debugger.

To enable remote debugger in app service:

1. Go to Azure management portal
2. Select your app
3. Go to **settings**
4. Go to Debugging
5. Enable **Remote Debugging**
6. Select your visual studio debugger versión

Comment: There is no Debugging tab/options anymore in Azure

Answer (score 0):

As much as it pains me to provide this as a solution, have you tried closing and re-opening Visual Studio?  (In particular if you were able to connect at one point and it stopped working.)  This has solved this issue for me on multiple occasions.

Answer (score 0):

Changing my network connection appeared to solve this for me. To do this, I:

1. Open Networking and Sharing Center
2. Change adapter settings
3. Disable the currently-active network adapter (ethernet in my case)
4. Enable another network adapter (WiFi in my case)

After that, Visual Studio debugged the app service.